# Bootstrap 3 tooltips not positioned correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dynamically generated list of moderators on a minecraft network with a tooltip generated for each head that is generated showing their username on hover. The functionality works, the tooltip generates and has the correct username in it however, the position is wrong. It's shifted to the left and falls apart as I move down the list. Here's a gif on what's happening:

[image]

I simply do not know what to do in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Well the plugin seems to work correctly (if the names are okay), I suppose it might be a css issue. Maybe the parts of the tooltip get somehow some margin on them. try to inspect them with right click and see if they have any other style attributes than the defaults.
Anyway, if you could post some of the codes, that would be easier.

Comment: See it live http://thecoremc.net/beta/index.php?action=players then go to the moderators section

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this page has changed since you asked this question, but I bet it was a CSS issue. You probably needed to center the tooltip box relative to its parent.  Here's some (unvetted) code that might help. I've only included the properties that would affect the centering on the tooltip container:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

Notice, you have to set a width on the `tooltip-container`. `margin-left` is 1/2 the width, and negative (visualize that `left: 50%` will put the left edge of the container at the center of the parent, and the negative `margin-left` will shift the container half the width of the container).